# How to add a symbol definition to Actions Frame in Adobe flash?

Tags: flash, frame, symbols, action

this is a super newbie question, but i can't figure it out. I have a flash project(not mine), where i can find several symbol definitions in the Actions Frame. How to add symbol definitions there? I managed to create symbols by dragging (for example) items from library on stage and then pressing F8. I can get a reference on them in the Action Layer(frame 1) under Scene1, but i would like to know how to add these under Symbol Definition(s). Sorry for the question, but i am new to Flash Professional. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The Symbol Definitions area of the actions frame is not actually where you create anything but is simply a shortcut for navigating to frames where actions have been written. Any items you see under the "Scene 1" (or whatever your scene is named) item are actions that are written on the main timeline. Any that you see listed under Symbol definitions are actions that are written on individual movie clips.

When you dragged a library item on stage and hit F8, it gives you the dialog to create a new symbol. You'll notice that it will then be listed in your library. You can do the same thing to turn drawing items into symbols. If you double click on your symbol in your library, you'll open up the view for that particular item. The timeline will then be specific for that symbol and not the same as the main timeline. If you then add an action to that symbol's timeline, your symbol will now show up under the Symbol Definitions list in the actions frame.